# Python requests.post calling own api function inside same Flask app

Tags: python, flask

My code is trying to check the login username and password, and if match, just send a new post request to localhost /api/homepage with data "values", I tried it in local virtual env of the python scripts and it works, but for production mode, after inputting the user name and password, 502 Bad Gateways occured. I have already imported 'requests' library.in Nginx setting no load balance is used.

```
@app.route('/api/login',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    username = request.form['usermail']
    pw = request.form['password']
    db=MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","1234","4080")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    query = "select * from user where username='"+username+"' AND password='"+pw+"';"
    try:
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
    except:
        db.rollback()
        return query

   if len(result)==1:

       values ={'user':'wes'}
       r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1/api/homepage' ,data=values)
       return  r.content

   else:
       return 'Fail login'

@app.route('/api/homepage',methods=['POST'])
def Display_Homepage():
    return request.form['user'];
```

Comment: Be sure you update this code to have proper query parameterization, because your current implementation is open to SQL injection. http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#some-examples

Comment: Thanks but i wanna know the reason of 502 bad gateways

Comment: At what point did you get Bad Gateway? In this script or when trying to post to this script? Can you successfully hit `'http://127.0.0.1/api/homepage'` externally to this program?

Comment: @tdelaney, yes, this code externally to this program

Comment: usually 502 errors are for an error which you don't handle it. so you should find a traceback in your logfiles